# Yamaha 02R V1 console

Tags: audio

I have a Yamaha 02R V1 mixer I'm trying to connect it to the speakers I have here at home they are connected to a receiver how can I get sound from the mixer to the receiver to use the system I already have my console has (stereo out) then also it has a headphone jack out ) or maybe I could get a plug to use for monitor out in have rca on the other end I really need help

Comment: Hello Daaron, It is unclear what you're asking. You should try to make your question more clear.

Comment: I have a sound system installed in my theater but it running off of a theater receiver I just got a  Digital  Console I'm wanting to connect my aux in dvd in mics to the console and I wanting to get that sound from the console to me receiver for sound to come out the speakers my what components would I use to get this job done

Comment: That comment was even more confusing! Is there not a RCA stereo out on the 02R? I can't find an image of the V1s rear panel, only the V2.

Comment: What's a Receiver, Do you mean Amplifier?

Answer (score 1):

What it sounds like you are trying to do is not advisable.  You really don't want to try to cross a consumer receiver with a professional mixing board.  They are not designed to be used together.  Impedances and line levels won't match and the alterations that the receiver will likely make to the sound are not desirable compared to a simple amplifier.